# class in python 3 not working as expected

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I have started work on a program that will allow a user to easily take pictures with the raspberry pi camera. The problem I am having is the class I have created does not do what I expected. When the code is run there is no output, what should happen is the Picture_Name_Settings function should be run. I'm still new to classes so I am probably missing something simple and the tutorials I have read online do not give a solution to my problem. Below is my code:

```
import picamera, time

class CameraController:
    def _init_(self):
        pass

    def Picture_Name_Settings(self, user_name, automatic_name, name_setting):
        pic_name = input("To name the image input N\nTo use automatic naming input A ")
        pic_name = pic_name.upper()
        if pic_name == "N":
            user_name = input("Please enter the name of what you want your image to be called ")
            name_setting = 1

        if pic_name == "A":
            current_time = (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
            current_date = (time.strftime("%d:%m:%Y"))
            automatic_name = "".join(("Image taken at ", current_time, " on the ", current_date, ".jpg"))
            name_setting = 2

    def Camera_Capture(self):
        self.Picture_Name_Settings(user_name, automatic_name, name_settings)
        if name_setting == 1:
            picture_name = user_name
        if name_setting == 2:
            picture_name = automatic_name

        camera = picamera.PiCamera()
        camera.capture(picture_name)
```

Comment: You only define a class. Defining a class does not run any code. It's like defining a function

Comment: How do I run the class?

Comment: Hello - unless you're **sure** you mean _init_, it's likely you want a double underscore on line 4 - so `def _init_(self):` becomes `def __init__(self)`. [Here's](http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/class-init.html) a basic runthrough of what the `__init__` method does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare user_name, automatic_name and name_setting variables as instance variables and you should be fine

```
class CameraController:
def _init_(self):
    pass

def Picture_Name_Settings(self):
    pic_name = input("To name the image input N\nTo use automatic naming input A ")
    pic_name = pic_name.upper()
    if pic_name == "N":
        self.user_name = input("Please enter the name of what you want your image to be called ")
        self.name_setting = 1

    if pic_name == "A":
        current_time = (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        current_date = (time.strftime("%d:%m:%Y"))
        self.automatic_name = "".join(("Image taken at ", current_time, " on the ", current_date, ".jpg"))
        self.name_setting = 2

def Camera_Capture(self):
    self.Picture_Name_Settings()
    if self.name_setting == 1:
        picture_name = self.user_name
    if self.name_setting == 2:
        picture_name = self.automatic_name

    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
    camera.capture(picture_name)
```

Comment: I understand what you have done but it does not solve the problem of the function not running

Comment: controller = CameraController()  
controller.Camera_Capture()  
this should call the method

Comment: So I type those into the idle window?

Comment: No, you add that to the bottom of your python file. Without indentation. In 2 lines: `controller = CameraController()` and `controller.Camera_Capture()`

You should read up on how classes work, what a class definition is and how to call methods in classes.